# I am facing error in render-flex overflow at the bottom of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════

A Render-Flex overflowed by 99437 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column at line no. 37
```

This is the accounts page.

```
import 'package:amazon_clone/model/order_request_model.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/model/product_model.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/model/user_details_model.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/providers/user_details_provider.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/screens/sell_screen.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/utils/color_themes.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/widgets/account_screen_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/widgets/custom_main_button.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/widgets/products_showcase_list_view.dart';
import 'package:amazon_clone/widgets/simple_product_widget.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AccountScreen> createState() => _AccountScreenState();
}

class _AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = Utils().getScreenSize();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AccountScreenAppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: screenSize.height,
          width: screenSize.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const IntroductionWidgetAccountScreen(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: CustomMainButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      "Sign Out",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    isLoading: false,
                    onPressed: () {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    }),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: CustomMainButton(
                    child: const Text("Sell",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    color: yellowColor,
                    isLoading: false,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const SellScreen()));
                    }),
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("users")
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                      .collection("orders")
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                          snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Container();
                    } else {
                      List<Widget> children = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
                        ProductModel model = ProductModel.getModelFromJson(
                            json: snapshot.data!.docs[i].data());
                        children.add(SimpleProductWidget(productModel: model));
                      }
                      return ProductsShowcaseListView(
                          title: "Your orders", children: children);
                    }
                  }),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    "Order Requests",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("users")
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                          .collection("orderRequests")
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                              snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Container();
                        } else {
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                OrderRequestModel model =
                                    OrderRequestModel.getModelFromJson(
                                        json:
                                            snapshot.data!.docs[index].data());
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    "Order: ${model.orderName}",
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle:
                                      Text("Address: ${model.buyersAddress}"),
                                  trailing: IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection("users")
                                            .doc(FirebaseAuth
                                                .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                            .collection("orderRequests")
                                            .doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id)
                                            .delete();
                                      },
                                      icon: const Icon(Icons.check)),
                                );
                              });
                        }
                      }))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IntroductionWidgetAccountScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroductionWidgetAccountScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserDetailsModel userDetailsModel =
        Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context).userDetails;
    return Container(
      height: kAppBarHeight / 2,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: backgroundGradient,
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: kAppBarHeight / 2,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white.withOpacity(0.000000000001)],
            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            end: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 17),
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: "Hello, ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                        fontSize: 26,
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      // text: "${userDetailsModel.name}",
                      text: userDetailsModel.name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                        fontSize: 26,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/116KbsvwCRL._SX90_SY90_.png",
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please someone help to solve this problem...
Please share code where I am making mistake in code !!

Answer (score 0):

Remove fixed height from SizedBox,

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          // height: screenSize.height, //<< this 
          width: screenSize.width,
          child: Column(
```

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e3684 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold

Comment: Accounts screen is also blank

Comment: can you simplify the widget,

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean ??

Comment: I am trying to simplify the code

Comment: Instead of providing full snippet try to create a new widget that will reproduce the same error. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There is something issue inside FutureBuilder

Comment: try to remove `Expanded`  and use `shrinkWrap:true` on listView, though I will suggest just to remove top SingleChildScrollView

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't worked. It's okay. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: have you got the soulution ?

Comment: No bro, I have commented FutureBuilder